# How to increase execution timeout in AWS-S3 Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, amazon-cognito, awss3transfermanager

S3 Storage getting timed out after 50 minutes when uploading larger size video and throws below error. We have tried changing AWSS3TransferUtilityTimeoutIntervalForResource as above 50minutes but still 
not working. Please let us know how to increase execution_timeout on SDK file.

---

### NSURLErrorDomain error -1001

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change timeout in AWSS3TransferUtilityTimeoutIntervalForResource. Rationale, workaround and solution are mentioned [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/773).
Basically multi part file upload is your way to go.